# Would the following trade scenario trigger a wash sale?

Tags: stocks, trading, wash-sale

I am new to stock trading and am confused by the usage of the word "before" in the wash sale rule. There is one scenario in particular that I am confused on. For simplicity's sake, let's assume the following are the only moves I make on ABC all year. Take the following example:

Monday: Buy 100 shares of ABC at $10. Later that same day, I sell all 100 shares at $11.

Tuesday: Buy 100 shares of ABC at $10. Later that same day, sell all 100 shares at $8.

Is this scenario going to trigger a wash sale? If so, how does this play out when it comes to taxes?

Comment: Where are you? Tax questions require a country tag.

Comment: Do other countries have a wash-sale rule ? Also aren't day-traders exempt from wash-sale rules ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really just to expand on Bob Baerker's answer and clarify the before language and where that might apply.

Consider these transactions:

```
Day 1: Buy 100 Shares XYZ for $1,000

Day 20: Buy 50 Shares of XYZ for $700

Day 20: Sell 50 Shares of XYZ for $400
```

The day 20 sale results in a loss.

Either way, this loss is washed because within 30 days of the transaction that resulted in a loss you opened a position in a substantially similar security.  Depending on the accounting you're using, usually FIFO (first in first out), you would have sold 50 of the Day 1 shares or all of the Day 20 shares.

After the sale you're now holding, for simplicity lets just use FIFO.

```
Day 1: 50 Shares of XYZ which cost you $500

Day 20: 50 Shares of XYZ which cost you $700

Disallowed loss of $100
```

The disallowed loss needs to be applied to either the shares in the Day 1 or Day 4 transactions.

So from a tax standpoint you're holding:

```
Day 1: 50 Shares of XYZ which cost you $600

Day 20: 50 Shares of XYZ which cost you $700
```

If on Day 50 you sell 50 more shares of XYZ and there is a loss, your loss would be washed by the Day 20 buy.

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of the wash sale rule is to prevent investors from selling a security at a loss so they can claim tax benefits, only to turn around and immediately buy the same security again (within 30 days before or after realization of the loss).

In your example, the first trade is a gain.  It has no relevance to a wash sale because there was no loss.  Your second round trip was a loss but you did not repurchase shares (which remain open) in order to realize the loss while maintaining the position.

Comment: I'm not sure where you get the rule in the second paragraph from. See [Investopedia](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/w/washsale.asp). "To be more specific, a wash sale involves selling a security at a loss and repurchasing the same security, or one that is substantially identical, within 30 days before or after the sale." The second sale *is* a wash sale. The purchase can be before or after, closed or open, and at a gain or at a loss.

Comment: You need to go beyond your quoted sentence and look at the sequence of trades and the entire position.  Second sentence of your link: "Wash sales are a method investors employ to try and recognize a tax loss without limiting their exposure to the security."  The OP has no exposure since all purchases are closed.  There is no adjustment of cost basis. There is no loss deferral.  Your link negates your conclusion.

Comment: No. That a particular sale doesn't exploit the loophole wash sales were intended to avoid doesn't mean that it's not a wash sale. My quote clearly explains what the definition of a wash sale is, and you can double check it with the IRS. The law clearly requires an adjustment of cost basis. (This is a case where the wash sale rule does strange things for no good reason. It's not a perfect rule that always and only catches people doing bad things.)

Comment: Please square your answer with the text of [26 USC 1091(a)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/26/1091), the law that definitively states which losses are disallowed under the wash sale rule.

Comment: Your reading didn't disallow a loss.

Comment: @quid Yes, it does. The loss in the second sale is disallowed, per 26 USC 1091(d) it adjusts the basis of the first sale. Please just read the law. It's not ambiguous or unclear at all. The second sale, under 26 USC 1091(a) is a wash sale. Under 26 USC 1091(d) it adjusts the basis for the first sale. This is an atypical affect of the law, but it is the law.

Comment: @David Schwartz - You don't understand what you are citing.  It doesn't disallow the loss (OP's transactions).

Answer (score -1):

Under US law, the second sale is technically a wash sale. The [definition of a wash sale in the United States](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/w/washsalerule.asp) is a sale of a security at a loss in which you bought any other shares of an identical, or substantially similar security, within 30 days before or after the sale.

All the elements are met here. The sale on Tuesday was a sale at a loss. The purchase on Monday was for different shares of the same security and it was within 30 days.

So the answer to your question is yes. As a consequence, you must add the loss in the second sale to the basis of the first stock. This results in the first sale being reported as a loss for tax purposes.

The time at which the shares in the substantially identical security are sold has no effect on the operation of the wash sale rule.

The wash sale rule is intended to catch people who close positions just to mine them for tax losses where they have another purchase that prevents the loss from really being taken. However, it is not perfect and it does occasionally apply to situations in which there is absolutely nothing nefarious going on. Fortunately, it doesn't really do any harm here -- it just moves the loss in time by a small amount.

**Update:**

Here is 26 USC 1091(a):

> In the case of any loss claimed to have been sustained from any sale or other disposition of shares of stock or securities where it appears that, within a period beginning 30 days before the date of such sale or disposition and ending 30 days after such date, the taxpayer has acquired (by purchase or by an exchange on which the entire amount of gain or loss was recognized by law), or has entered into a contract or option so to acquire, substantially identical stock or securities, then no deduction shall be allowed under section 165 unless the taxpayer is a dealer in stock or securities and the loss is sustained in a transaction made in the ordinary course of such business. For purposes of this section, the term “stock or securities” shall, except as provided in regulations, include contracts or options to acquire or sell stock or securities.

If you think the rule doesn't apply, then please state which part of the test isn't satisfied. The second sale is a loss. There is an acquisition in the 60 day period. The securities are identical. So no deduction is allowed for the second sale. We're not talking about a dealer. The law is very, very clear.

Comment: The "before" language is to include short selling activities where the sale occurrs chronologically before the buy and the buy is the transaction that may result in a loss.  When you apply the rule in a manner that you describe the loss occurs now chronologically earlier which means a shrewd investor could shove a loss in to a prior tax year; opening a whole new loop hole.  Really though, there's a circular effect, now the Monday sale results in a loss, which would need to step up the cost basis of the Tuesday buy, and so on.  The government WANTS the $1 gain from the Monday transaction.

Comment: @quid I understand that it's very weird that the wash sale rule works this way, but it in fact does. The wash sale rule closes a big loophole and, yes, it does open a small one. The wash sale rule moves a loss in time and it can move it forwards or backwards. (The before language is also there because just as you can buy the replacement stock immediately after the wash sale, you could also buy it immediately before. There's no practical difference.)

Comment: It 100% does not.  The Monday transaction is closed and resulted in a gain.  The Tuesday position is closed and resulted in a loss.  There are no other open positions, so there is nowhere to put the loss proceeds unless a new position is opened within 30 days of Tuesday's sale.

Comment: @quid There is nothing about the wash sale rule that says the loss has to be moved to an open position. That is usually what happens, but it can just as well move the loss to a closed position. There is no requirement that the share holding periods overlap. Please read the [actual law](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/26/1091). It is very, very clear that it applies to this situation.

Comment: `If your loss was disallowed because of the wash sale rules, add the disallowed loss to the cost of the new stock or securities (except in (4) above). The result is your basis in the *new* stock or securities. This adjustment *postpones* the loss deduction *until* the disposition of the *new* stock or securities. Your holding period for the *new* stock or securities includes the holding period of the stock or securities sold.` from Pub 550.  Postpones.

Comment: @quid That is a statement explaining how to apply the wash sale rule to transactions the wash sale rule applies to. It's not telling you how to tell whether or not the wash sale rule apples to the sale, which is what we're talking about. I added a citation to the actual law in my answer, PLEASE read it. That part of Pub 550 is trying to explain 26 USC 1091(d) which does not contain any such ordering requirement and is, in fact, clear that the order can be either way.

Comment: That is a quote from IRS Pub 550 which explains the application of wash sale rules.

Comment: Yes. It's explaining [26 USC 1091(a) and 26 USC 1091(d)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/26/1091) which I strongly encourage you to read as it makes it 100% clear that the wash sale rule applies. I agree that Pub 550 doesn't explain every nuance of the law, nor is it intended to.

Comment: You have taken a reading of this rule that completely negates the point of the law by reaching back in time to swing a position that was closed resulting in a gain in to a position that is still closed but now a loss, potentially in to a prior tax year.  In order to adjust the basis of a position, the position needs to be open.

Comment: @quid There is nothing odd about my reading of the law. This is precisely what the law says. Yes, you could consider this a tiny loophole, but the law's purpose is to close a very big loophole. In any event, the law is really clear that it applies to this situation. Nothing about the law is ambiguous. The law is intended to move losses in time.

Comment: Your reading completely contravenes the laws intent.  The law is not intended to move losses in time.  The laws intent is to disallow tax-losses where the taxpayer still has an interest in the position.  Your reading still allows the loss, but moves it back in time.

Comment: @quid The rule is precisely intended to move losses in time. If I close a position this year but open the same position and close it next year with no change in its value, the effect of the rule will be to move the loss forward in time. That's precisely the intent of the law.

Comment: If I buy and sell two lots within 30 days of each other, both at a loss, your linked 26 USC 1091 (a) is telling me both losses are disallowed because of the other purchase; (d) is not explicit about where the basis ends up, unless it's up to me(???) to elect that time flows like an arrow and a later purchase moves loss to the basis of the second purchase.  As a non-lawyer taxpayer, it's enough for me that Pub 550's time flows like an arrow.

Comment: @user662852 I gave you a link to the law which you claimed to have read. Yet 26 USC 1091(c) explains how this case is handled. Your argument that because one word in Pub 550's attempt to explain the law by example doesn't apply to this situation that means the law doesn't apply even though nothing in the law is ambiguous is kind of absurd.

Comment: I admit I didn't recognize (c) applied because of a "not less" = "greater than or equal to" sloppy misreading but I agree with you on closer parsing.   Since (c) states "the particular shares ... shall be determined under regulations prescribed by the Secretary" I am now confident in my personal position that Pub 550 (=regulations prescribed by the Secretary of the Treasury) can be understood by their plain English understanding in cases where (c) applies, and loss is thus postponed.  Btw I'm not @quid but you engaged me in a related question and this chain fit better.

Comment: @user662852 This rule is so complicated that almost nobody gets it 100% right. It's a good thing brokers are required to compute this for their customers and I feel truly sorry for anyone who trades using foreign brokers or multiple brokers/accounts and has to work this out for themselves. Fortunately, I can't imagine the IRS will care if you do something technically wrong that just changes when a loss is materialized inside the very same tax year and generally speaking, there's no penalty for good faith mistakes that don't cause tax underpayments.

Comment: @user662852, the loss is postponed for a 30 day window within which if you are to buy the security (or substantially similar security) you would have to step up the basis of that transaction to account for the loss.  It does not postpone the loss back in time to an already closed position.

Comment: @quid Where are you getting that from? It's not in the law.

Comment: `determined under regulations prescribed by the Secretary.`

Comment: @quid Okay, then I hope we agree that we are talking about a sale at a loss for which the wash sale applies and then need to consult the regulations prescribed by the Secretary to determine which shares get the step up in basis. The law specifies what transactions the wash sale rule applies to and is unambiguous in how to make that determination. The Secretary specifies which shares get the increase in basis when the wash sale rule applies to a transaction. You can't make that argument unless you agree with my answer -- in this case, there's only one possible place the basis can go.

Comment: It is one thing for the rule to apply, it is a wildly different thing for it to have an actual impact.  Does the sale described in the question become trapped by the rule, technically yes.   Yes, the loss occurred within 30 days of an acquisition.  Does the sale get captured by the wash sale rule, yes.  And, if more shares are purchased in the next 30 days the cost basis would need to be stepped up to account for that loss, otherwise there is no impact and the first transaction books as a gain while the second transaction books at a loss.

Comment: @quid The question is whether this is a wash sale, that is, whether the wash sale rule applies. And my answer is that yes, technically it applies. I think we're in 100% agreement now.

Comment: I disagree with your 3rd paragraph.  Your answer is yes it applies and you have to adjust your first, already closed, transaction.

Comment: @quid We agree that the wash sale rule applies, right? That means that the loss is disallowed, per 1091(a). 1091(b) doesn't apply. 1091(c) says the Secretary decides which shares get the basis adjustment. But here, there is only one transaction that it could possibly apply to. Are you saying you adjust the wash sale itself? That's impossible because that would conflict with 1091(a)'s unambiguous statement that the loss is disallowed on that transaction. It has to go somewhere else.

Comment: No, I've very explicitly said numerous times that you don't adjust anything because there is no open position to adjust.  You wait for 30 days, if a new position is opened you adjust the cost basis of that new position.  Based on pub 550 `determined under regulations prescribed by the Secretary`

Comment: @quid The law very explicitly says that the loss is disallowed and must adjust the basis of some other transaction. Nothing in the law permits anything else. The Secretary gets to decide which of the possible shares that could be the ones disallowing the loss are the ones that actually are considered to disallow it and thus get the basis adjustment. But there's only one possibility here. The Secretary can't create an exception to 1091(a) as no law allows that.

Comment: Do you at least see our disagreement right now?  You think you can look at a law and stop there, even though the law says someone else will determine the application.  There is nothing to adjust.  You have no interest in the security so you can't adjust nothing.

Comment: The law says someone else will make one very specific determination, that of which shares are considered to be the one's disallowing the loss. The law is entirely unambiguous about this. I don't think you are disagreeing with me so much as disagreeing with the law.

Comment: No, I'm definitely disagreeing with you.  You don't adjust closed positions.